# Editing cloud formation templates terminates existing instances and creates new instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

We are using a cloud formation template for a set of VMs and each time after the code deployment , we need to edit the package version on the template parameters for auto scaling to take the latest package from the s3 bucket.

The issue is, editing cloud formation template triggers a cloudformation-based upgrade of the instances(which involves destroying the existing machines and creating new ones from scratch, which is time consuming).

Is there anyway we can prevent this.

Basically, we dont need the cloud formation template to destroy and recreate the instances whenever we edit it.?

EDIT : This my autoscaling group setting

```
    "*********":{
        "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
        "Properties":{
            "AvailabilityZones":[
                {
                    "Ref":"PrimaryAvailabilityZone"
                }
            ],
            "Cooldown":"300",
            "DesiredCapacity":"2",
            "HealthCheckGracePeriod":"300",
            "HealthCheckType":"EC2",
            "LoadBalancerNames":[
                {
                    "Ref":"elbxxbalancer"
                }
            ],
            "MaxSize":"8",
            "MinSize":"1",
            "VPCZoneIdentifier":[
                {
                    "Ref":"PrivateSubnetId"
                }
            ],
            "Tags":[
                {
                    "Key":"Name",
                    "Value":"my-Server",
                    "PropagateAtLaunch":"true"
                },
                {
                    "Key":"VPCRole",
                    "Value":{
                        "Ref":"VpcRole"
                    },
                    "PropagateAtLaunch":"true"
                }
            ],
            "TerminationPolicies":[
                "Default"
            ],
            "LaunchConfigurationName":{
                "Ref":"xxlaunch"
            }
        },
        "CreationPolicy":{
            "ResourceSignal":{
                "Timeout":"PT10M",
                "Count":"1"
            }
        },
        "UpdatePolicy":{
            "AutoScalingRollingUpdate":{
                "MinInstancesInService":"1",
                "MaxBatchSize":"1",
                "PauseTime":"PT10M",
                "WaitOnResourceSignals":"true"
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So that we can answer your question, can you provide further information? For example, what do you mean by "edit the package version on the template parameters for auto scaling"? Can you provide relevant snippets of your CloudFormation template? What behaviour are you wanting from the existing instances when you update the parameters? Feel free to Edit your question to provide additional details.

Comment: Sure, I have now pasted the cloud formation template. When ever I edit the parameters, this should not create new and terminate my existing instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the documentation and view the `Update requires:` field on the property you modifying on your CF template.

If it says `Replacement` it will recreate the instance, with a new logical id

If it says `Some Interruption` it will make the instance unavailable, in the ec2 case, restarting it, but will not recreate the instance, keeping the same logical id

If it says `No interruption` it will not impact the instance at all

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have updated the question with the autoscaling group setting.  There can I specify that it should not terminate and recreate the instances whenever I edit the template, using 'willreplace' or any other equivalent parameter ?